# How to use Wifi on Ubuntu with a dual boot (macbook air)?

Tags: wireless, 13.04, macbook-air

I'm new on Ubuntu system and i do not manage to run the Wifi, I am using Ubuntu with a dual boot on a Macbook Air 6,2, 
Type of card :  AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x117)
Version of internal program :   Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (6.30.223.154.63)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to connect to Ethernet (via usb dongle) and run

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source﻿`

If you are not able to get access to Ethernet, you can download this file on another machine, transfer it via usb, and install it that way.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2